# Showing an $L^1$ function must be 0 by the boundedness of a potential type integral. Is there a cleaner way?

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the problem:

Let $f\in L^1$ satisfy
$$\limsup_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{|f(x)f(y)|}{|x-y|^2 + \epsilon^2} dxdy < \infty$$
Show that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

I've got what I think to be a solution to this problem, but I don't find it to be very elegant. Denote the integral by $I(\epsilon)$. It involves restricting to a strip of width $h$ along the line $y=x$ and using Lebesgue Differentiation. I have to do a bunch of basic-type estimates on the integral, and what I finally get is that $I(\epsilon) \geq C \frac{1}{h} \int_K |f|^2$, where $K_n$ is a sequence of compact set which increase to $\mathbb{R}$, minus perhaps a null set. Letting $h \to 0$ shows that $\int_K |f|^2 = 0$, so that $\int_K |f| = 0$.

So I effectively hit the integral with a bunch of rather crude estimates. But this is a qual problem, whose solutions I'm used to being a little more clean. Is there any easier way? I can provide details to my solution, but if you have anything that looks better than what I've outlined above, I'd like to see it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas: 1. By the monotone convergence theorem, the $\limsup$ equals

$$\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{|f(x)f(y)|}{|x-y|^2} dxdy.$$

2. Suppose $f= 0$ a.e. fails. Then there is a set $E$ of positive measure and a constant $c>0$ such that $|f|>c$ on $E.$
3. A.e. point of $E$ is a point of density of $E.$ If $x$ is a point of density of $E$, then it seems probable to me that

$$\int_E \frac{1}{|x-y|^2} dy =\infty.$$

Comment: Of course. Thank you so much.